# How to import the local image from the machine into apache superset dashboard

Tags: python, html, tableau-api, dashboard, apache-superset

I can not upload the image in the apache superset dashboard. My image is in C drive and I want that image in my dashboards.

Using HTML and Using Markdown, we can upload image. But I want to load the image from the drive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.